# Microsoft GraphApi: how to filter SPO results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a SPO site within a SPO site collection.
My site has a DocumentLibrary and inside it 3 folders (Alfa, Beta and Gamma): I would like to get get the ID of one of them (for example Beta) by Graph API.

I can get all of them by writing:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[id site collection]/sites/[id site]/drives/`

I can select a specific fields:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[id site collection]/sites/[id site]/drives?$select=name,id`

but I can't filter the results, the following requests return always the same results of the first one:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[id site collection]/sites/[id site]/drives?$filter=name eq 'Beta'`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[id site collection]/sites/[id site]/drives?filter=name eq 'Beta'`

. Does anyone know why and explain me how to filter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you cannot use ODATA query parameter `$filter` to filter the document libraries as it is documented that it can [support only few query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters). There is already a feature request raised in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=filter%20drives), please upvote it so that the product team may develop it in future.

For now you should query it on your end(Client side) using [list drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list) and pick the required drive object by the name property from drive objects listed.